# Between any two points in $R^n$ lies another point

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-geometry

Finishing up baby Rudin ch. 2, I was doing problems and realized that I had not seen a proof that given $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $q \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $d(p,q) > 0$, there exists another point $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $0 < d(p,z) < d(p,q)$. In fact, the first proof relating to $\mathbb{R}^n$ in Rudin, that all open (or closed) balls are convex, states that if $|y-x| < r$, and $|z-x| < r$, and $0<\lambda<1$, then the result of $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$ is in that open ball as well. But this only states that such a point *would* be, the existence of two such points in an open ball is not assumed (or even necessary).

I've spent some time looking for evidence of this proposition in chapter 2, but I haven't found anything yet; the only contenders seem to be the proofs of compactness, but I think they hold without it (although they do depend on the LUB property of the reals). At first I thought I was being too pedantic, or that this should be trivial to prove, but I tried to sketch some ideas (other than directly showing that you can solve for such a point $z$ between $p$ and $q$ by the distance metric formula) but I didn't come up with anything right away. I don't think it's a hard problem, but now I'm getting curious if maybe, in Rudin, this was avoided on purpose as an unnecessary complication, or was tacitly assumed?

Comment: What is wrong with the convexity argument you gave? Take the point $z = (p+q)/2$, which is halfway between $p$ and $q$. This point certainly exists (because addition in $\Bbb{R}^n$ is well-defined), and it satisfies the inequality.

Comment: That point certainly exists:  scaling and adding are fine operations.

Comment: @Nick That's a succinct and satisfying proof, and it really takes the wind out of this question's sails, but in the best way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The completeness of the reals I hope we can assume, and it comes up in any first real analysis course. Then you can argue inductively to extend the result to $\mathbb{R} ^n$, I reckon.

Then what you can do is say, assume that $\mathbb{R} ^n$ is complete. Then for $\mathbb{R} ^{n+1}$ we have that this is a direct product of two complete spaces. So for any a, b we have that we can take $a+ \lambda *(b-a)$. As the first n co-ordinates are in $\mathbb{R} ^n$, and the last is in $\mathbb{R}$ we have that it exists.

This question is also, to some extent, about the reals being hausdorff, and as you have a metric on this space, they are hausdorff (all metric spaces are.) Though I do feel you're looking for a more tangible solution than "it is".

Comment: Completeness is irrelevant to the stated property: e.g., it holds in $\Bbb{Q}^n$: just take $\lambda$ to be any to be any rational in $(0, 1)$.